# How can i find the below map got synchronized

Tags: java, hashmap, synchronization, synchronized

i am just synchronizing the HashMap using `Collections.synchronizedMap(map);` then adding values to the map as shown below. And in second scenario i have added keys and values to the map then i am doing synchronization to map object. But i did not find any difference in the output.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SyncHashMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
        map.put(10, "ten");
        map.put(20, "twenty");
        map.put(30, "thirty");
        map.put(40, "forty");
        map.put(50, "fifty");

        System.out.println(map); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{50=fifty, 20=twenty, 40=forty, 10=ten, 30=thirty}
```

In another scenario:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SyncHashMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(10, "ten");
        map.put(20, "twenty");
        map.put(30, "thirty");
        map.put(40, "forty");
        map.put(50, "fifty");
        map = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
        System.out.println(map); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{50=fifty, 20=twenty, 40=forty, 10=ten, 30=thirty}
```

Is there any difference in between these outputs. Otherwise any particular way to find difference in synchronizedMap method while using. Need some clarification.

Comment: Your code is single-threaded, so you couldn't see any difference between the two. You should make the map synchronized **before** using it in a multi-threaded environment! And don't forget, that all parallel accesses should be done through the synchronized map returned by `Collections.synchronizedMap` as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29

Comment: You're not confusing synchronizing with sorting, are you?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup i know that synchronizing and sorting is entirely different. But i just want to check how this `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` will work in multi-threaded environment with an example.

Comment: If you want to check how this works in a multi-threaded environment, then you should add some threads.